# ionic 2:Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm getting an error when I try to build my app with

> ionic run android

this is the error

```
[14:38:19]  lint finished in 1.88 s
[14:38:33]  Error: Error at
            C:/Users/adirz/myapps/studentAssistantApp/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:943:29
[14:38:33]  Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

I added the course-page.ts component

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, LoadingController,AlertController,NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';


//import providers
import {CoursesData} from "../../providers/Courses-data";
import firebase from 'firebase';

/*
  Generated class for the CoursesPage page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-courses-page',
  templateUrl: 'courses-page.html'
})
export class CoursesPage {
  public pet: string = 'SemA';
  public coursesA: Array<any> = [];
  public coursesB: Array<any> = [];
  public department:any;
  public gaming: string = 'all';
  public courseNames: Array<any> = [];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private navParams:NavParams,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,public coursesData:CoursesData,public alertCtrl: AlertController) 
  {
    console.log("adir");
      this.department=this.navParams.get('department');
      console.log(this.department.id);

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
   let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({});

    this.coursesA=this.coursesData.getCoursesList(this.department.id);
    if(this.coursesA){
      console.log("hello world");
      console.log(this.coursesA);
       loader.dismiss();

    }
     //this.coursesData.getCourse(this.department.id)ף

    /*this.getCoursesList().then((x: Array<any>) => {

      if (x) {
        this.coursesA = x;
        this.courseNames = x;
        loader.dismiss();
      }

    }); 
    */

  }
```

I added also the course-data provider

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import firebase from 'firebase'

/*
  Generated class for the CoursesData provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class CoursesData {
  //firebase datab
 public fireRef:any;
 public coursesList:any;
  public coursesA: Array<any> = [];

  constructor() {
   this.fireRef=firebase.database().ref();
   this.coursesList=firebase.database().ref('Courses/');
  }

  public getCourse(departmentId:any):any{
      var semesterRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA');
      return semesterRef;
  /*semesterRef.on('child_added', function(courseSnapshot) {
    console.log(courseSnapshot.key);
    courseSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot):boolean{

      return courseSnapshot.val(); // to appease TypeScript
    });
  });
  */


  } 

  public getCoursesList(departmentId:any):any
  {
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA');
  var listChild =[];
        rootRef.on('child_added', function (childData) {

          childData.forEach(function(childData2){
           listChild.push(childData2.val());          
            return false;
          })
        });
        return(listChild);

    }
  }
```

I guess it's something with my return from  function in course-data.ts `getCoursesList(departmentId:any):any`

I think I did something wrong.

when I run ionic serve it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by change into the parameters of the functions here. i marked the arguments with mark quote ? means that not necessary to pass them.

```
C:/Users/adirz/myapps/studentAssistantApp/.tmp/pages/courses-page/courses-page.ngfactory.ts:943:29
```